# Check if new data entered into array matches any of the already entered data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I made a code where the text entered in a textbox is pushed in a array which then displays on click of a button. The code is like:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);


app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

$scope.ss = [];

$scope.sa = [
        {plate1: 'some plate 1'},
        {plate1: 'some plate 2'},
        {plate1: 'some plate 3'},
        {plate1: 'some plate 5'}
    ]
alert($scope.ss.length);    
$scope.getPlate = function(){

$scope.ss.push({plate1:$scope.newplate});
    //var abb= $scope.ss.push.apply($scope.sa).toString();

//  var aas = $scope.ss;

}

});
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="xx in ss track by $index">
            <td>{{xx.plate1}}       </td>
            <td>            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="text" ng-model="newplate"/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="getPlate()"/>


</div>
```

Now i need to check that if the text I enter is present already, then it should not be pushed. Pls help.

Comment: To push unique data in Array, you need to compare data to be pushed with array elements

Comment: @user3450590, check my answer please..

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`Array.prototype.some()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
$scope.getPlate = function() {
  var exists = $scope.ss.some(function (value) {
    return value.plate1 == $scope.newplate;
  });
  if (exists) {
    // it exists
  } else {
    $scope.ss.push({plate1:$scope.newplate});
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.ss = [];
var match=[];
$scope.getPlate = function(){
   if(match.indexOf($scope.newplate) > -1){
        match.push($scope.newplate);
        $scope.ss.push({plate1:$scope.newplate});
    }
}
});
```